# VBA ByRef argument type mismatch in Excel 2019

Tags: vba, excel-2019

Another failed attempt to escape from VBA. I am trying to parse a string in Excel VBA into two variables. I do bring up the non-common sense portion in my head to work on it but still no luck.

```
Sub StartEndMonth(ByVal MonthRange As String, ByRef MonthStart As String, ByRef MonthEnd As String) ' xxx-xxx
    MonthStart = "Jan"
    MonthEnd = "Dec"
End Sub

Sub TestMonthList()
    Dim Month_Range, Start_Month, End_Month As String
    Month_Range = "Jan-Dec"
    StartEndMonth Month_Range, Start_Month, End_Month
    MsgBox MonthRange & " " & Start_Month & " " & End_Month
End Sub
```

The above code throws the VBA ByRef argument type mismatch error on the Start_Month variable in the calling routine. I should have some parsing logic inside the StartEndMonth routine. I still got the compile error after I have eliminated everything else in the routine.

Suppose every variable has been properly defined? Or not?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't know why/how this works but usually closing the argument in a bracket solves that issue. In this case, it would be  **StartEndMonth Month_Range, (Start_Month), End_Month**. I tried it and got the output message as "Dec"

Comment: @Charlie Thanks for the response! Allow me to share how I just solve the issue - type over the code all over again - long live Microsoft!

Comment: *type over the code all over again"* that's never the right approach, and it certainly is not Microsoft's fault that you did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, don't write subs/functions that modify their arguments. If you calculate something, *return* it, e.g. as an Array:

```
Function SplitMonthRange(MonthRange As String)
    SplitMonthRange = Split(MonthRange, "-")
    ' you really should add some sanity checks, e.g. UBound() and value checks
End Function
```

Then the res works very straight-forward:

```
Sub TestSplitMonthRange()
    Dim monthRange as String, months As Variant

    monthRange = "Jan-Dec"
    months = SplitMonthRange(monthRange)

    MsgBox monthRange & ": " & months(0) & " to " & months(1)
End Sub
```

---

Hint - this:

```
Dim Month_Range, Start_Month, End_Month As String
```

declares 2 Variants and 1 String. This is correct:

```
Dim Month_Range As String, Start_Month As String, End_Month As String
```